# Chef recipe doesn't run service

Tags: chef-infra

I have the following code in my recipe:

```
service "myapp" do
  supports :restart => true, :start => true, :stop => true
  action :nothing
end 

bash "install myapp" do
    cwd "/var/lib/myapp"
    code <<-EOH
    npm install myapp
    EOH
    timeout 86400
    notifies :start, "service[myapp]"
end
```

The chef recipe runs correctly and I can see the following output in my console:

```
212.71.1.1   * service[myapp] action start←[0m
```

However, the service doesn't really start.. If I log in manually and run 'service myapp start' it works just fine..

I tried running the knife bootstrap command with `-VV` but no further info was provided on the console

Comment: Wild guess here, but maybe Chef thinks that the service is already started, so it doesn't start again. You could try notifying a `:restart` instead, that might do the trick.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the capability of the service, but not your desired actions.

```
service "example_service" do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

Documented [here](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_service.html)

### Update

Why don't you use the [npm](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/npm) cookbook? If it works as advertised your recipe would look more like a normal package install and service declaration:

```
npm_package "myapp" do
  version "1.2.3"
  path "/var/lib/myapp"
  action :install
end 

service "myapp" do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

Comment: I believe that the OP doesn't want to either enable or start the service during its declaration. He's correctly stating `action :nothing` and then notifying it to start when the `template` resource runs.

Comment: @cbl I'm not a nodejs user, but there is a npm cookbook available.